# Why iterator doesn't have any reset method?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Why? And what the best way to move iterator items pointer to the first position?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Why?

Because if you force iterator to have a reset method *every* iterator has to have a reset method. That gives every iterator writer extra work. Plus some iterators are really hard (or really expensive) to reset, and you wouldn't want users to call reset on them. Iterators over files or streams are good examples.

> what the best way to move iterator items pointer to the first position?

Create a new iterator. It's rarely more expensive than the reset.

Comment: (Except the fact that there is a `remove` method, which *doesn't* actually really give all iterators "extra work", as the operation is optional.)

Comment: @aioobe There are some cases where removing the current object via iterator makes life really easy for developers. There are very few cases where this is true for reset (because you can almost always create a new iterator).

Comment: @DJClayworth "That gives every iterator writer extra work." That's not a reasonable response. Library implementors need to do a little extra effort, but the payoff is that many library users will get the benefit.

Comment: The much more important point is the second one, that some iterators are impossible to reset.

Comment: What if an iterator is a method parameter? If I want changes to an iterator to be propagated to method caller... I just can't, right?

Answer (score 7):

Once you read a stream, you can't re-read it without opening the source again.  That's how streams and iterators work.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to create a new one!

Comment: The exact same way you created the previous one: Iterator<T> iterator = iteratable.iterator();

Answer (score 3):

This is a general tendency adopted in JCF - keep the interface minimalistic , unless that makes some feature extremely difficult to work. This is the reason why you do not have separate  interfaces for semantics like immutable collections, fixed-size collections ..

As to why then a `remove(Object)` is provided ( as optional ) - Not providing this would make it impossible to safely remove an item from a collection while iterating over the collection - there is nothing that makes providing a `reset()` so compulsary.

Again , why there is a separate `ListIterator()` ( providing methods like `previous()` and `previousIndex()`  ) - With a `List` interface , the main functionality while it is being used is the ability to layout the elements wrt an index, and to be able to access them with an index-order , whether fixed or random order. This is not the case with other collections.Not providing this interface for a `List` will make it very difficult if not impossible to work smoothly with a list.

Comment: There are a few things that can be done with almost any `Iteratable` and `Iterator`, which could usefully have been included in the interface but weren't.  Useful iterator methods would include `skip` [equivalent to N consecutive move calls, though many iterators could implement it in time O(1)] and `copyLocation` [which would return an iterator which is expected to yield the same items as the original].  Any iterator could implement a `skip` method, and any non-huge finite iterator could implement `copyLocation` by enumerating itself to an array, and then having both it and the copy...

Comment: ...return items from that array.  Client code could perform either operation itself, but if an iterator has special knowledge about its inner workings that client code lacks, it could use such knowledge to offer many-order-of-magnitude speed improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Tip: create your iterator variable as a function instead, then you can consume it as many times are you want. This only works if the underlying logic is repeatable.

Example in Scala (Java similar but I don't have a Java REPL handy)

```
def i = (1 to 100) iterator   // i is our iterator
i.grouped(50) foreach println // prints two groups
i.grouped(50) foreach println // prints same two groups again
```