# Find an element over an Iterable

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have the following class:

```
public static class GenerateMetaAlert implements WindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Boolean>, Tuple2<String, Boolean>, Tuple, TimeWindow> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Tuple key, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> collector) throws Exception {
        //code
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is is for each element of the collection there are any other with the opposite value in a field.

---

An example:

```
Iterable: [<val1,val2>,<val3,val4>,<val5,val6>,...,<valx,valy>]
               ||           ||          ||          ||
              elem1        elem2       elem3       elemn
```

What I would like to test:

```
foreach(element)
   if elem(i).f0 = elem(i+1).f0 then ...
   if elem(i).f0 = elem(i+2).f0 then ...
   <...>
   if elem(i+1).f0 = elem(i+2).f0 then ...
   <...>
   if elem(n-1).f0 = elem(n).f0 then ...
```

I think this would be possible using something like this:

```
  Tuple2<String, Boolean> tupla = iterable.iterator().next();
  iterable.iterator().forEachRemaining((e)->{
  if ((e.f0 == tupla.f0) && (e.f1 != tupla.f1)) collector.collect(e);});
```

But like i'm new with Java, I don't know how I could do it in an optimal way.

---

This is a part of a Java program which use Apache Flink:

```
.keyBy(0, 1)
.timeWindow(Time.seconds(60))
.apply(new GenerateMetaAlert())
```

---

> Testing:

Using the following code:

```
public static class GenerateMetaAlert implements WindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Boolean>, Tuple2<String, Boolean>, Tuple, TimeWindow> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Tuple key, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> collector) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("key: " +key);
        StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.f0)) // yields a Map<String, List<Tuple2<String, Boolean>>>
                .values()                                  // yields a Collection<List<Tuple2<String, Boolean>>>
                .stream()
                .forEach(l -> {
                    System.out.println("l.size: " +l.size());
                    // l is the list of tuples for some common f0
                    while (l.size() > 1) {
                        Tuple2<String, Boolean> t0 = l.get(0);
                        System.out.println("t0: " +t0);
                        l = l.subList(1, l.size());
                        l.stream()
                                .filter(t -> t.f1 != t0.f1)
                                .forEach(t -> System.out.println("t: "+ t));
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
key: (868789022645948,true)
key: (868789022645948,false)
l.size: 2
l.size: 2
t0: (868789022645948,true)
t0: (868789022645948,false)
```

Conclusion of this test: is like the condition `.filter(t -> t.f1 != t0.f1)` is never met

If I change `.filter(t -> t.f1 != t0.f1)` for `.filter(t -> t.f1 != true)` (or false) the filter works

I also use the following:

```
    final Boolean[] aux = new Boolean[1];
    <...>
    Tuple2<String, Boolean> t0 = l.get(0);
    aux[0] = t0.f1;
    <...>
    .filter(t -> !t.f1.equals(aux[0]))
```

But even with that, I don't have any output (I only have it when I use `t.f1.equals(aux[0])`

Comment: It's not really possible with iterator, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961456/how-to-copy-an-iterator-to-another-one

Comment: If you had `[<"a", true>, <"a", false>, <"a", true>]` then of course you would expect the second tuple to be collected, but what about the third?  The logic you presented suggests that you would want it collected, but I want to confirm.

Comment: And what if the `f` value flips back and forth several times, such as [<"a", true>, <"a", false>, <"a", true>, <"a", false>, <"a", true>, <"a", false>, <"a", true>]?  Do you then want to collect the same tuples multiple times (the last, for instance)?  Your logic suggests that, but I'm suspicious that you actually want to to collect a tuple only when its `f1` differs from the immediately preceding tuple's, as opposed to collecting each tuple as many times as it has preceding tuples with the same `f0` and different `f1`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I would like to collect the tuples several times due I need to check if the valy of `[<valx,valy>...]` has change in each tuple an return an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

An `Iterable` allows you to obtain as many `Iterator`s over its elements as you like, but each of them iterates over *all* the elements, and only once.  Thus, your idea for using `forEachRemaining()` will not work as you hope.  Because you're generating a new `Iterator` to invoke that method on, it will start at the beginning instead of after the element most recently provided by the other iterator.

What you can do instead is create a `Stream` by use of the `Iterable`'s `Spliterator`, and use a grouping-by `Collector` to group the iterable's tuples by their first value.  You can then process the tuple lists as you like.

For example, although I have some doubts as to whether it's what you actually want, this implements the logic described in the question:

```
StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.f0)) // yields a Map<String, List<Tuple2<String, Boolean>>>
    .values()                                  // yields a Collection<List<Tuple2<String, Boolean>>>
    .stream()
    .forEach(l -> {
        // l is the list of tuples for some common f0
        while (l.size() > 1) {
            Tuple2<String, Boolean> t0 = l.get(0);
            l = l.subList(1, l.size());
            l.stream()
                    .filter(t -> t.f1 != t0.f1)
                    .forEach(t -> collect(t));
        }
    });
```

Note well that that can collect the same tuple multiple times, as follows from your pseudocode.  If you wanted something different, such as collecting only tuples representing a flip of `f1` value for a given `f0`, once each, then you would want a different implementation of the lambda in the outer `forEach()` operation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try what you have proposed and let you know if this work for my use case.