# Java switch case breaks method

Tags: java

I have a simple switch case. And a simple method.

The problem is, for some strings in the switch case, while calling the same method.
The method returns a diffrent result.

case: "list.all" is calling listALL()
results in the follwing output

```
listAll - start
processor: process.listAll key: :06.2003, value: 69.0
processor: process.listAll key: :08.2003, value: 88.0
listAll - end
```

case: "list" is calling listALL() .. the same method as before
but now the result is

```
listAll - start
listAll - end
```

Not clear to me why the "switch" impacts the result of the method.
Can someone explain this please?

```
  @Override
  public void process(String action, String v) {

        switch(action)
        {
            case ("delete"):
                this.delete(action, v);
                break;
            case ("list"):
                this.listAll();
                break;
            case ("list.all"):
                this.listAll();
                break;
            default:
                this.upsert(action,v);
        } // end switch

        context.commit();
    } // end process



public void listAll() {
            System.out.println("listAll - start");
            KeyValueIterator<String, WrapperMinMax> iter = this.kvStore.all();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                KeyValue<String, WrapperMinMax> entry = iter.next();
                System.out.printf("processor: process.listAll key: :%s, value: %s\n", entry.key.toString(), entry.value.getMax());
            }
            iter.close();
            System.out.println("listAll - end");
        }
```

Comment: Whatever the issue is, it has nothing to do with what is passed as a parameter to `process()`, since the same method is being called both times. Therefore, the only other possible cause has to be the while loop, which isn't running the second time. Are you sure this issue is unique to those calls? Does it work multiple times in a row when different parameters are passed to `process()`?

Comment: Put break point in `listAll` method if it is called for both cases it is not the problem of your switch case, it seems that `this.kvStore.all()` return empty `iter` in second call

Comment: This thread has some good advice on different ways to remake an iterator for usage if you want some options on how to go about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961456/how-to-copy-an-iterator-to-another-one

Comment: The order of calls has no influence, 
I can call "list" first and it returns no result
And call "list.all" 2nd and it returns results. 

Also the number of calls has no impact, the "list.all" works 10 times in a row
as the whole processor gets started for each new incoming message.

I just changed the "list" string into the string "dall" and then both calls
produce the expected output.
Im just totaly confused, why only changing the string in the switch, changes the result of the method. no other chnage made besides replaceing the string in switch.

Comment: Show your `this.kvStore.all();` method

Comment: The thing is that somewhere in your code you exceed the iterator that is returned by `this.kvStore.all();`

Answer (score 3):

I think because here `this.kvStore.all();` you are not creating new iterator but reuse the one that has exceeded already.

Hence calling `while` loop once eats up all the iterations and the second run gets `iter.hasNext()` returning `false`.